# Problem of using element.addEventListen("keydown", function) over document.addEventListener("keydown", function)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

I have a NodeList of button elements *numbers*. I want each of the elements listen to keydown event in respective to their own textContent.

When I use document.addEventHandlers("keydown", *function*), it works fine.

**Method 1:**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
numbers.forEach(number=>{
    if (number.textContent === e.key){
        addNumber(number)
    }})})
```

However, it stops working when I use this instead:

**Method 2:**

```
numbers.forEach(number=>number.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
    if (number.textContent === e.key){
        addNumber(number);
    }}))
```

The first method seems not efficient to me since it has to make comparison to every items in numbers everytime "keydown" is fired. Can anyone tell me why the method 2 don't work as method 1?

Comment: You need to be focused on the button element for the keydown event to work if you're adding the keydown event to the button (ie: number) itself. Are you focusing the button element first? (you can click tab so it highlights blue, or click the element to focus it and then try typing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
    numbers.forEach(number=>{
        if (number.textContent === e.key){
             addNumber(number)
        }})})
```

In the above code, you are adding a keydown listener for the document itself, so whenever you press a key on the keyboard, this event is fired.

```js
     numbers.forEach(number=>number.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
         if (number.textContent === e.key){
             addNumber(number);
         }}))
```

In this code, you are adding a keydown listener to the individual element, so only if the element is focused the keydown event will be fired for that element

Comment: I add that to make the element focusable you need to add the "tabindex" attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the performance, you can map your numbers in a map/dictionary with their textContent as a key and the number object as a value. Then:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    var number = numbersByKey[e.Key];
    if (number)
        addNumber(number);
})
```